# Auto incrementing composite key

Tags: python, database, composite-primary-key, datajoint

I have a relatively simple need -- I have a table with a composite primary key that includes an integer index to be autoincremented. However, I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have read [the documentation](https://docs.datajoint.org/python/v0.11/definition/07-Primary-Key.html) which suggests the following

```
U().aggr(Scan & key, next='max(scan_idx)+1')

# or

Session.aggr(Scan, next='max(scan_idx)+1') & key
```

However I find these lines to be extremely cryptic and haven't been able to find any further documentation of the aggr method or what next= means. Can someone please provide a minimal example illustrating their use? Thanks.

Comment: I should note I also tried this in a dumb way by incrementing manually in the body of the transaction, but fell into a world of pain with collisions everywhere

Comment: Computing `max(scan_idx)+1` sounds like it offers a good **hint** for a value to choose, but it's racy. It doesn't guarantee collison-free values. Either adopt a single-column PK with the usual autoincrement, or take on the responsibility at the app level of always having to supply a unique value pair.

Comment: @J_H thanks. I'd like to know how to use these lines though. As in, what is the expected output and how do I get an autoincremented index from them? The output type seems to be an empty query

Comment: Where are you 1st stuck? Otherwise this is just another duplicate  Q&A for yet another presentation to not understand. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre] Quote with credit & format as quote what is needed to ask, make your post self-contained. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, automatic generation of primary key attributes for real-world entities generally ought to be avoided. The purpose of the primary key is *entity integrity*: to establish a 1:1 correspondence between real things and their digital representations in the database. This requires assigning identifying information in the external world. Auto-increment can make it too easy breaking this 1:1 association. However, there are many cases when auto-increment is appropriate, especially in cases where the entity only exists in the application with no real-world counterpart.

Second, this type of client-side auto-increment is racy (as already noted by a commenter), so it needs to be done inside a transaction. DataJoint's `make` functions are executed within transactions, so you are good there. But in other cases, you can use the transaction context of the `dj.Connection()` object.  The `aggr` method is the right method for incrementing but needs explaining. I will provide a complete example here.

Let's consider the definition for `Session` and `Scan` as in your original question. A session can have multiple scans.

```py
@schema
class Session(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    session : int 
    ---
    session_info : varchar(1000)
    """

@schema
class Scan(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    -> Session
    scan : int
    --- 
    scan_info="": varchar(1000)
    """
```

Here Scan has a composite primary key `('session', 'scan')`.

Let's populate `Session` with a few entries:

```py
Session.insert(
    (1, "Awesome"),
    (2, "Splendid")))
```

Now let's insert scans for a specific session with auto incrementing `scan`.

```
session_key = {'session': 1}  # select session 

with dj.conn().transaction:
   # insert scan with a new id
   scan_ids = (Scan & session_key).fetch('scan')
   next_scan = max(scan_ids, default=0) + 1
   Scan.insert1(dict(session_key, scan=next_scan, scan_info="wow!"))
```

Note that the `with` block constitutes an isolated atomic transaction. This prevents any conflicts introduced by concurrent transactions. Transactions cannot be nested. Therefore, if this code is already inside a transaction, then omit the `with` statement.

The `aggr` query allows performing the max operation on the server side. This may be preferable if the number of scan_ids is high and you would like to avoid sending the entire set of existing ids over to the client.